# Run query cypher on tomcat, error with Scala library

Tags: java, scala, tomcat7, neo4j

I'm tring to run a query with cypher in a web app(REST) with tomcat. 
This code works correctly in a normal java application, but if I run it on the web app with tomcat it returns this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
```

if I add a scala-library.jar into project when I deploy on tomcat it return an error "OutOfMemory". Searching on the web, I have increased my JAVA_OPTS from 512M to 2048M but nothing.

This is my code to execute my query:

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );  
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( query );
```

It looks like the ExecuteEngine makes use of Scala library and this library conflicts with tomcat.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:

(full stack OOME)

```
16-apr-2012 16.25.10 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:644)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:547)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantUtf8.<init>(ConstantUtf8.java:48)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:129)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2156)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2077)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2034)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1923)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1891)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1877)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:855)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    ... 8 more
16-apr-2012 16.25.11 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
16-apr-2012 16.25.11 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
16-apr-2012 16.25.11 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13147 ms
```

Comment: There should be no conflicts with Scala and Tomcat. Exactly which version of Apache Tomcat and also post the full stack trace of the OOME.

Comment: How much data are you returning? It could be a huge result building up on the server side ...

Answer (score 0):

The noclassdeffound is due to the missing Scala library so adding it to web-inf/lib is correct.  Adding a library to the classpath won't lead to out of memory errors though, so it seems to be related to your app.

What is the class ExecutionEngine? What's the stacktrace (although that won't necessarily help).  Are you sure your webapp is doing the same as your java app which has no problems?  How are you testing your webapp? Could it simply be that many concurrent threads (requests) cause the OOME, but one thread works fine (like the plain java app)?